# Export a field from custom model grid with a diferent render to Csv

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, sales-order, order-grid, renderer

I created a custom column on sales order grid. It works as well but a used a custom render on a field (like [this](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/08/26/magento-admin-grid-add-custom-column/)).

When I export the grid to CSV, the file contains the raw value, but I need apply another render to it for users understand the data.

So how I can do a custom render to column on grid just to export cases?

Answer (score 9):

I got it. There is the renderExport method to do it.

My render file:

```
class Namespace_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Renderer_Grid_MyModule extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());

        // CUSTOM PHP CODE FOR MODIFY VALUE HERE

        return $value;
    }

    public function renderExport(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        return $this->render($row); // We can do diferent value for Render Grid and Render Export.
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add in your answer as well (in short) where / how you configured to use that renderer for your filed (just to make this more complete) Or provide a link to a resource on how to do that.